# swift to objective C set image prom facebook login

Tags: objective-c, swift, image

How can I write the code below in Objective C:

```
let strPictureURL: String = (result.objectForKey("picture")?.objectForKey("data")?.objectForKey("url") as? String)!
self.ivUserProfileImage.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: strPictureURL)!)!)
```

I have been trying to rewrite the code in objective C and don't find a way to set an image from a NSString. So far I have managed this:

```
NSString *strPictureURL = [[[result objectForKey:@"picture"] objectForKey: @"data"] objectForKey:@"url"];
```

Comment: Why are you trying to convert `objectForKey:` to `valueForKey:`. Use `objectForKey:`.

Comment: Have you attempted to translate the code to create the `NSURL` from the `NSString`? Then the `NSData` from the `NSURL`? Then the `UIImage` from the `NSData`? You don't need to look at Swift code to write such code in Objective-C.

Comment: You're right @rmaddy. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work like this:
             NSString *strPictureURL = [[[result objectForKey:@"picture"] objectForKey: @"data"] objectForKey:@"url"];
             UIImage *im = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strPictureURL]]];
             [self.imageProfilePic setImage:im];

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *strPictureURL = [[[result objectForKey:@"picture"] objectForKey: @"data"] objectForKey:@"url"];    
self.ivUserProfileImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strPictureUrl]]];
```

Comment: I've given your code a try, it does not popup errors. But it doesn't update the uiimage with the image from the nsstring either. And I have printed strPictureURL and it looks ok.

Comment: You're probably better of splitting each step in different objects to look at their values in sequence. Try declaring each object i.e NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strPictureUrl]]; , and then UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data]; That way you'll be better able to understand what is going on

Comment: I was just going to make the same comment. Never nest so much code into one line. It's impossible to debug and hard to read.